# What is a Fuel Over Pressure Protector?

Tags: wing, airbus-a320

What is a fuel over pressure protector on the A320 and other aircraft? What is the purpose of this hole?

Comment: I think the subject of [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/descending-aircraft-making-noise-like-giant-blown-bottle) is somewhat related (but *not* duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to overfill a wing. You fuel the aircraft when its wing is cold. Later as the aircraft sits on the ramp the outside temp increases causing the full to expand in an already full wing. So they have the overflow system dumps the excess fuel on the ramp. Its usually not a lot of fuel just a few gallons.
  It also prevents the fueler from over fueling the wind. It can sometime dump 50 gallons or more if the fueler it not paying attention.

Comment: I was recently on an MD-88.  As soon as the door closed the captain came on....Always a bad sign.  He said that he had just been told of a fuel leak.  It turns out that the fueler had overfilled the aircraft and it had vented.   We had to wait around for a maintenance check, a cleanup crew, a ramp approval and a fire department approval (hazardous waste spill?) before we were finally able to depart.